# R Script Length, thousands of command

Tags: r

This may be a lofty goal but here goes...

I have the following code in my R console:

```
main.df <- data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,5), ncol = 5))
names(main.df) <- c("date","numeric.date","wStatus","temp","zipId")
```

I'm looking to add data to `main.df` with the following code:

```
readW <- readLines("http://www.wunderground.com/weather-forecast/00705")
temp <- readW[555]
status <- readW[549]
main.df[1,4] <- temp
main.df[1,3] <- status
```

followed by ...

```
readW <- readLines("http://www.wunderground.com/weather-forecast/00610")
temp <- readW[555]
status <- readW[549]
main.df[2,4] <- temp
main.df[2,3] <- status
```

and so on...

I've built a script that references >40,000 zipcodes but when I try to execute R ceases to respond. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: This is very hacky...Do they have a public API?  That would be the best case scenario.

Comment: true...i'll check for a public API

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @darwin - there was a much easier way to do this by using the weather underground's public API.

Comment: Great, I hope it works out.